# Get axes from matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, axes

I have an animation plot, with 4 sub plots. The plots `ax1` and `ax2` share the same scale - hence I could plot the `ax2` y-axis on the right hand side y-axes of `ax1`.

```
ax1.plot(df.pnl.as_matrix(),color='black')
ax2.plot(df.unit.as_matrix(),color='black')

axi = ax1.twinx()
axi.set_ylim(ax2.get_ylim())
```

Which crates the following plot:
[image]

But obviously I don't want the `ax2` subplot to contain the data from `df.unit.as_matrix()` - as I would rather use it for something else. So my question is, how to I get the axes that `ax2` creates, without actually using `ax2`. I.e. is there a way to derive it from the matrix `df.unit.as_matrix()`, and somehow use that, instead of `ax2.get_ylim()`.

In essense what I am asking, is what method does matplotlib use to create the axes from a 2D matrix - then I could just replicate that and use `ax2` subplot for something more useful.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. What is `ax2`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnes `ax2` is what I am using to get at the prefered y-axes for the right hand side of `ax1`. I.e. I am using `ax2` in this case to get the axes of  df.unit.as_matrix(). Both have the same scale, but I don't actually want to plot ax2.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnes `ax2` is a subplot. I supplse what I am asking is what method does matplotlib use to create axes. Then I could use that method instead of creating a new plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  sorry got the name wrong. If you can't answer this I will leave it.

Comment: Still not sure what the problem is; so let me ask differently: What would be the problem if you removed the line `ax2.plot(df.unit.as_matrix(),color='black')` from your code?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the problem would be that the rhs y-axes of the `ax1` plot would not exist. I am only using `ax2` to get the axes array of df.unit.as_matrix(). If I had another method of making an axes from df.unit.as_matrix() I could use that.

Comment: The y scale of `ax2` goes from the minimum of `df.unit` to the maximum of `df.unit`, plus 5% margin on each side by default.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  ok thanks, but how do I get that onto the rhs of `ax1`?

Comment: by setting it as ylim for `ax2`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ah, I see, it's just 2 values. I should have looked before I started making assumtions. I assumed it would have been an numpy array with some kind of scaled linspace. Thanks for your time.